# Javascript : looping array of arrays. If match found, push to array, if not, create new innerarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I'm retrieving information from a database. The data looks like this (I've simplified it):

```
    var example = [
    {'start': 1966, 'end': 1970},
    {'start': 1969, 'end': 1971},
    {'start': 1972, 'end': 1980},
    {'start': 1974, 'end': 1985},
    {'start': 1975, 'end': 1979},
    {'start': 1986, 'end': 1990},
    {'start': 1991, 'end': 1995}
          ];
```

What I want to do is sort this dynamically into a new, empty array `newArr`. When the sorting is done `newArr` should look like

```
var newArr = [
    [
        {'start': 1966, 'end': 1970},
        {'start': 1972, 'end': 1980},
        {'start': 1986, 'end': 1990},
        {'start': 1991, 'end': 1995}
    ],
    [
        {'start': 1969, 'end': 1971},
        {'start': 1974, 'end': 1985}
    ],      
    [
        {'start': 1975, 'end': 1979}
    ]];
```

I'm new with javascript. The reason I've chosen for this combination of arrays and objects is because I'm using JSON data in which the order of objects is important

**What I want to do and what I tried**

I'm trying to group the objects on the different keys of the main array (newArr[0], newArr[1] etc . I want to iterate through `example` and put objects on a certain key. if in the iteration of example the property `end` is lower than what at that moment is on newArr, there is an overlap and a new array should be made. Else it should be pushed in to the main array key where where there is no overlap. I've tried doing this with the the following three functions

```
    var newArr = [];

    function _overlap(){
    // place first object
    var addFirst = [example[0]];
    newArr.push(addFirst);

    // place others, therefore start with i = 1;
    for (var i = 1 ; i < example.length ; i++){
        _checkOverlap(example[i]);  
    }   
}   
_overlap();

    function _checkOverlap(input){
    // traverse the main array newArr, example[i] is passed as argument input
    loopJ:{
        for (var j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++){
            // compare value of input.start (so example[i]) with last key of inner array
            var innerArrayLength = newArr[j].length; // I need this to get the last key: length -1
            if (input.start > newArr[j][innerArrayLength-1].end ){
                newArr[j].push(input);
                console.log(newArr);
                break loopJ;                    
            } else {
                _createNewArr(input);
                break loopJ;
            }
        }           
    }
}

    function _createNewArr(input){
    var toBeAdded = [];
    toBeAdded.push(input);
    newArr.push(toBeAdded);
}
```

This code does exactly what I want on the first key newArr0 , but never pushes into the other keys. Should I use a recursion in this case? I've tried so many things, but the amount of browsers crashes due to infinite loops is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can we assume the `end` in each entry is greater than the corresponding `start`, and that in `example` the entries are sorted by `start`?

Comment: Looking at your expected output I don't understand how you are sorting

Comment: @Oriol : yes, it always greater. And the start value is sorted , it comes from a sorted mysql query, with lowest values first and then descending.

Comment: So, if the `start` is lower or equal to `end` of the previous added interval, you want to have a new array?

Comment: @depperm : I might got confused somewhere. Basically what I want to do is: compare the value of input.start with the highest values of the keys of the innerarrays. So if I have newArr[0], newArr[1] and newArr[2], with, for example, newArr[0] having 6 entries (so the highest key is 5), newArr[1] has 12 and newArr[2] has 5, I would like to compare (and immediately stop if input.start is higher than it) input.start with newArr[0][5], newArr[1][11], newArr[2][[4] and push it when the condition is met and break the loop. If the condition is never met, I would like to make a new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, for each entry of `example` you must search the first group in `newArr` where the entry can be added. If you find that group, add the entry and iterate the next entry. If you don't find that group, just create a new group at the end.

```js
var newArr = [];
outerloop:
for(var entry of example) {
  for(var group of newArr)
    if(group[group.length-1].end < entry.start) {
      group.push(entry);
      continue outerloop;
    }
  newArr.push([entry]);
}
```

Comment: This is way easier to read than the recursive approach I was thinking of, awesome!

Comment: I've been bumping my head against the wall, trying to write so much lines of code only to backspace it and now I see this. So elegant, short and it works. Thanks a lot! I'll take my time to see what you did and understand it :)

Answer (score -3):

why don't you use a comparator function inside `arr.sort`

```
 var example = [
{'start': 1966, 'end': 1970},
{'start': 1969, 'end': 1971},
{'start': 1972, 'end': 1980},
{'start': 1974, 'end': 1985},
{'start': 1975, 'end': 1979},
{'start': 1986, 'end': 1990},
{'start': 1991, 'end': 1995}
      ];

//sorting using comparator function
example.sort(function(a,b){return a.start-b.start}) //will sort on start date
```

Comment: He doesn't want it sorted, he wants to exclude the year-interval that overlaps and put those in separate groups.